# Can't update a component's state inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {contents: []};
}

componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('> Manage mounted');
    ServerService.getServers(
        Parse, 
        self.props.parentState.state.activeAccount,
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error); 
            }

            this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
              contents: results 
            }));
        }
    );
}
```

Hi there, I have this code above. I have a component named Manage and Servers. Now, from the time the Manage component is mounted, I wanted to populate it's this.state.contents by means of `ServerService.getServers()`. The utility returns a `results`, which is an array from a callback function. Though, the state is not getting in. Is this the correct way of updating a component's state from the within a callback function?

Furthermore, I am passing the said state  to a child component named `MainContent` e.g. `<MainContent contents={this.state.contents} />`, and watching it as a props, when the component is mounted

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('> MainContent is mounted');
    console.log(this.props.contents);
}
```

The thing is, `this.props.contents` from `MainContent` component remains a blank array. The reason why I am doing this is because I have further usage of the value in `contents`, as another sets of `props` for `MainContent` child components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach that you are using to update the state is useful in a scenario when you are trying to update a state sort of like

```
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
          contents: [...prevState.content, props.content]
        }));
```

i.e making use of the previous `state` as well as `props` because `this.props` and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

However you are using setState inside a function and hence `this` keyword here won't refer to the correct content, you should make use of `self` also since you are updating the state with a value that is not dependent on state or props and hence you can use the direct approach of updating a state like

```
self.setState({contents: results});
```

Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('> Manage mounted');
    ServerService.getServers(
        Parse, 
        self.props.parentState.state.activeAccount,
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error); 
            }

            self.setState({
              contents: results 
            });
        }
    );
}
```

As far as getting a blank array in `componentDidMount` of `MainContent` is concerned, you will get a bland array because componentDidMount is rendered only on the initial render and since at initial render your `this.state.contents` is a blank array, you get a empty value.

change that to `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("Main content");
    console.log(nextProps.contents);

}
```

Comment: hi @Shubham, thank you for your answer. Sorry I have further questions to ask. I updated my question above.

Comment: @TeodyC.Seguin Updated the answer for  your further queries

Comment: Thank you @Shubham, that was really helpful. I'm getting the populated array now.

Comment: Great, Glad to have helped