# Adding a state variable to another state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a state variable to another state variable.

**Why am I doing this?**

I'm using `Firebase` as a database and storing my (relatively small amount of) data through `state` in `React`. I could use different variables for each "set" of data, but I'm trying to see if it is possible using a single variable.

So, I'm creating different state variables (here: `child1` and `child2`), and at the end storing them, or rather `push`ing them into another state variable (here: `parent`), and finally storing the state `parent` using firebase only.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.addMember = this.addMember.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        parent: [],
        child1: [],
        child2: []
    };

    // const child1 = [0], child2 = [0];

    // Tried using the above and below methods as well!

    // const child1 = [];
    // const child2 = [];
}


addMember(member) { // member has a property of name

    switch (member.name) {
        case `child1`:
            this.child1 = [...this.child1].push(member)  // this throws an error as it is unable to access "undefined"
            break;
        case `child2`:
            this.setState({
                child2: [...this.state.child2, member]
            })
            break; 
        default:
            throw alert("something is reeeeeeally wrong")
            // break;

    }

    let counter = {...this.state.parent}
    counter[`${member.name}`].push(this.state.child2);
    this.setState({ parent: counter})


}
```

The above code uses examples from other answers, which show how to store and access data within a nested object in a state:

[React.js - What is the best way to add a value to an array in state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26505064/5283213)

[How to set a nested state in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040721/5283213)

[Accessing class variable declared in constructor in other parts of the app (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43829852/5283213)

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing to me but if you are trying to add items to an array to store it later in the state it's a better practice to build the entire array in a local variable and then set the state once instead of do a push and setState for each item.

Comment: @Rodius hadn't thought of it that way, I'll definitely try it that way. But I still want to know if what I am trying to accomplish is *possible* or not.

Comment: Is it required for `parent` to be an array?

Comment: @TPorter Not really, anything that works really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't advisable to store a state variable that is derivable directly from state or props. Instead you could store child1 and child2 as class variables and set parent state from them. Also what you are trying to do will not actually work out, since setState is async and you would need to handle it a little differently

An example of using class variable

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.addMember = this.addMember.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        parent: []
    };

    this.child1 = [];
    this.child2 = [];
}


addMember(member) { // member has a property of name

    switch (member.name) {
        case `child1`:
            this.child1 = [...this.child1, member]  
            break;
        case `child2`:
            this.child2: [...this.child2, member]
            break; 
        default:
            throw alert("something is reeeeeeally wrong")
            // break;

    }

    let counter = {...this.state.parent}
    counter[`${member.name}`].push(this.child2);
    this.setState({ parent: counter})
}
```

Comment: Could you share a source where I could read up on how I could handle it differently?

Comment: handling it differently meaning updating the state also into the switch component for parent. Also when updating state based on previous one, use the prevState updater function,  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197819/cant-update-a-components-state-inside-a-callback-function/42198053#42198053

Comment: ah. Thanks a lot!
btw, what's the difference between declaring the variables as `this.varname` and `const varname`, as I had perviously?

Comment: const varname has a scope limited to the enclosing `{}`, and then you write using `this.varname`, it has a scoped to your entire class

Comment: Hey, I just tried your code, and the last but one line still returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Sorry for the the mistake, it should be `let counter = [...this.state.parent]` updated that in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161166/discussion-between-thedarkknight-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 1):

If the shape of the parent object is guaranteed (meaning something like `child3` will never be added), the following would work

```js
state = {
  parent: {
    child1: [],
    child2: []
  }
}

addMember(member) {

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    parent: prevState.parent[member.name].push(member);
  }));
  
}
```